# как скрыть datepicker если на форме несколько полей с выбором дат

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Имеется форма поиска для пользователя, где несколько полей с выбором дат. Если пользователь выбирает поля с датой, то там, где календарик открылся, он сам больше не исчезнет пока пользователь не кликнет по какому-либо другому полю, кроме полей с селектором datepicker. Таким образом если кликать только по полям с датой откроется куча календариков. Как сделать так, чтобы календарь автоматически закрывался при выборе другого поля с датой!

Сам календарик отсюда: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/
Вот такая по сути пользовательская форма
...
<\th>

...

Comment: лучше код добавь, что бы твои объяснение можно было визуально видеть, а не представлять абстрактно...  И прочитай, будет полезно https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2780/Улучшение-содержимого-Как-создать-краткий-завершенный-и-достоверный-пример

Comment: $('.datepicker').datepicker({ 
    autoclose: true,
})

Comment: $('#selectDate').datepicker()
.on('changeDate', function(ev){                 
    $('#selectDate').datepicker('hide');
});